# Can't install apps through Android Market website?

Tags: google-play-store, installation

When I try to install an app from the Android Market website, I get this error:

> "There are no android phones associated with this account. Please sign in with a different account."

I tried fixing it by following [**this**](http://phandroid.com/2011/02/04/solved-android-market-website-says-there-are-no-android-phones-associated-with-this-account/), but it didn't help. I can see the list of apps that are already installed on my phone though.

Did anyone else encounter this problem? Any hints on how to fix it?

thank you!

Comment: Probably obvious, but are you signed into Market with the same Google account you have on the phone?

Comment: Where do you see the "list of apps"? On the web market?

Comment: I am signed in with the same account, yes. And I can see the "list" here https://market.android.com/account under "orders" tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

made it... after going to market *account -> settings -> edit*, i chose "show in menus" and now it works.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it sorted. Don't forget to accept this as the answer (when the two days are up).